# HTML 5 batch video encoder

Tags: macos, html, html5-video, batch-processing, encoder

i need to use HTML 5 on my website.

Videos are in H.264 format.

Non-WebKit browsers, say, Firefox does't supports it. Firefox needs MPEG-4 instead.

I surfed the Web a little, but not found anything for this task.

The questions are:

- Could you recommend some free batch video encoder (command-line or not), that supports all video/audio formats for HTML 5 video. I need to convert about 20 video files right now.
- What more video formats should be used to be crossbrowser friendly ? I know about H.264, OGG and some WebM (never heart about it). Is there any list of supported video formats for each browser ?

Thanks

---

Forget to mention: i'm on a Mac

Comment: browser video support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video

Answer (score 0):

for converters I use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and [super](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)